# I haveSecurityException: Permission Denial error

Tags: android

I am getting the following error:

```
ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.optionpricing/.optionListNew } from null (pid=1160, uid=2000) requires null
```

I am new to programming in Android and I could not make sense of the other postings related to my problem.  I wonder if there is an issue with the optionListNew class? Can someone lend a hand so I can move on to completing my app.  Also, the app runs in my virtual device, and I only get this error when I try to test it on my actual phone.
Any ideas are appreciated.  Below is the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.optionpricing" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".optionListNew">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OptionPricing"/>
        <activity android:name=".optionListNew"/>
        <activity android:name=".futureOptionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".currencyOptionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".gapOptionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".gapOptionList01"/>
        <activity android:name=".barrierSingleUpInActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".testActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".barrierlistview"/>
        <activity android:name=".barrierSingleDownInActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You added **"optionListNew"** activity twice in the manifest file.. remove below activity by deleting this line

```
<activity android:name=".optionListNew"/>
```

Your Manifest.xml code will become

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.optionpricing" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".optionListNew">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OptionPricing"/>
        <activity android:name=".futureOptionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".currencyOptionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".gapOptionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".gapOptionList01"/>
        <activity android:name=".barrierSingleUpInActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".testActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".barrierlistview"/>
        <activity android:name=".barrierSingleDownInActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

optionListNew is present twice in the manifest. Remove the second.